# Docker: How to authenticate for docker push?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Hi i'm trying `docker push`

```
[docker-simple-httpserver]# docker push myregistry/simplehttpserver:latest
The push refers to a repository [myregistry/simplehttpserver] (len: 1)
Sending image list
FATA[0000] Error: Status 403 trying to push repository simplehttpserver: "{\"error\": \"Unauthorized updating repository images\"}"
```

is there a way for me to specify the `username` and `password` on `docker push` command?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I would think they keep passwords off the command line for security reasons.

The way to do it is to login first then push.

https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_six/

```
$ docker login --username=maryatdocker --email=mary@docker.com
Password:
WARNING: login credentials saved in C:\Users\sven\.docker\config.json
Login Succeeded
```

Then push

```
$ docker push maryatdocker/docker-whale
The push refers to a repository [maryatdocker/docker-whale] (len: 1)
7d9495d03763: Image already exists
c81071adeeb5: Image successfully pushed
```

Comment: But how does a person use something like CJE to push the built image to the registry in the Jenkinsfile if you can't inline specify both the username and password to run a login in the terminal?

Comment: The login step shown here is manual and requires an interactive terminal and someone typing the password. One way to automate that would be seveibar's answer, another would be to use the same command here with `--password-stdin` - like so: `docker login --username=<user> --password-stdin <<<'password'`

Comment: --email is no longer valid for the docker CLI

Comment: worked for me without email
`docker login --username=maryatdocker`

Comment: email flag does not work anymore. maybe i shouldn't dig around in almost 10 year old posts.

Answer (score 55):

Typically you would specify your password using the interactive `docker login` then do a `docker push`.

For a non-interactive login, you can use the `-u` and `-p` flags:

```sh
docker login -u="${DOCKER_USERNAME}" -p="${DOCKER_PASSWORD}"
```

The [Travis CI docs for docker builds](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) gives an example of how to [automate a docker login](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#Pushing-a-Docker-Image-to-a-Registry).

See [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) for more details.

Comment: never put your password in the command line like that

Answer (score 11):

In case, one needs to login to the custom docker repo, use below:

```
docker login -u ${USERNAME} -p ${PASSWORD} ${DOCKER_REPOSITORY}
```

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer works perfectly fine! However, if you are trying to access a private registry, you may have to consider making the following change request.

```
docker login -u ${user_name} ${private_registry_domain}
```

Provide password, when it prompt for the same.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know you have to use `docker login`. The credentials will be stored in `/home/user/.docker/config.json` for following `docker push`es.

If you are after automation the command `expect` will be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

`docker login --username=YOUR_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME`

[image]

In this case your dockerhub password will be an access token.

Refer: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/#create-an-access-token

Answer (score 1):

If you are tagging image with IP then login docker registry with IP, If you are tagging image with domain-name then login docker with domain-name, Somehow docker doesn't like mixing IP and domain and failing.

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer to the question, but you can first login and then do docker push.

`docker login -unice-username`

After which it will prompt for a password. After successful login you can do docker push.

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

use "sudo docker login" not "docker login" as one uses the root account and the other uses your personal.

Personally I create the repo on dockers website prior to the upload.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31233917)

Comment: This helped me to resolve the " Error response from daemon: Head ...unknown: Bad credentials" where I was login to Docker without sudo but attempted to pull images with sudo. So, both logging and pull have to be done with a similar privilege

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  If "They" had there way they'd have removed my comment. As per the above. "This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review – 
Juan Fontes
 Mar 12 at 10:46"