# Is there an Amazon ECR Public Gallery equivalent for openjdk:8-jdk-alpine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dockerhub, amazon-ecr, amazon-ecr-public

I have a Dockerfile that pulls a Docker Hub image as follows

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
```

However, sometimes I get blocked by the pull rate limit from free usage. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65806626/4829626) suggests to use Amazon ECR Public Gallery images, I've looked a while but I did not find a certified replacement for openjdk, and the ones I found have no description.

I would like to know if anyone found a replacement on Amazon public ECR. It doesn't have to be openjdk, it can be an alternative such as amazoncorretto or any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use: `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/openjdk:latest`
See the ECR Public Gallery: https://gallery.ecr.aws/docker/library/openjdk