# Error using docker compose in AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm deploying my dockerized Django app using AWS Code Pipeline but facing some errors of Docker.

error:

```
Service 'proxy' failed to build : toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit.
You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

`docker-compose-deploy.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    depends_on:
      - db

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:
```

`buildspec.yml`

```yaml
phases:versions.
  build:
    commands:
      - docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up --build
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Hub limits the number of Docker image downloads (“pulls”) based on the account type of the user pulling the image. Pull rates limits are based on individual IP address. For anonymous users, the rate limit is set to 100 pulls per 6 hours per IP address. For authenticated users, it is 200 pulls per 6 hour period. There are no limits for users with a paid Docker subscription.

Docker Pro and Docker Team accounts enable 5,000 pulls in a 24 hour period from Docker Hub.

Please read:

- [https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/#:~:text=Docker%20Hub%20limits%20the%20number,pulls%20per%206%20hour%20period](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/#:%7E:text=Docker%20Hub%20limits%20the%20number,pulls%20per%206%20hour%20period).
- https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue
But I encountered in CodeBuild.
To resolve this I added this in my buildspec.yml

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Docker hub...
      - docker login -u=${DOCKER_USERNAME} -p=${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
```

replace env variables with your docker credentials.